# How to fix yml config

Tags: jupyter-notebook, yaml, github-actions

https://github.com/KillerJoke623/Practic

I've got a problem with my University practic, can you help me please

```
name: Jupyter
on:
workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout 
uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Setup Python
uses: actions/setup-python@v4.0.0
with:
cache: pip
python-version: '3.7'
- name: Install Dependencies
run: pip install -r requirements.txt
- name: Exeute Notebook 
run: jupyter-nbconvert --to html practic.ipynb
- name: Upload a Build Artifact
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.0
with:
name: Artifact
path: practic.html
```

Comment: I opened a PR from a fork correcting the indentation: https://github.com/KillerJoke623/Practic/pull/1. You can also use tools such as this [YAML validator](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator) to check the YAML indentation.

Comment: Sorry @GuiFalourd but now I've got another problem
 
Error: No file in /home/runner/work/Practic/Practic matched to [**/requirements.txt], make sure you have checked out the target repository

Should I just delete string "run: pip install -r requirements.txt". It seems like our lector just don't drop to us this file

Comment: You need a `requirements.txt` file at the repository root, with the necessary python dependencies to run the project. As it doesn't exist at the moment, you will need to add it according to the libraries you're using in the project. You'll probably need it in the future depending on what you are building, so you could eventually create it empty if you don't want to edit the workflow.